# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split' while splitting the rows with nan in python

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

df

```
Id      Place
Id1     New York,London,Russia
Id2     Argentina
Id3
```

I am iterating row wise and splitting the values. For third row and I am getting the error 'AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'. How to handle nan cases ?

My try

```
L1 = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    x = df['Place'].iloc[0].split(",")
    L1.append(x)
```

Comment: what is your desired output of example? your code is wrong, and also your code didnt raise error. so you should make desired output of example.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas.Series.str.split` directly and it will handle `nan` for you:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Place":["a,b", "a", "z", np.nan]})

L1 = df["Place"].str.split(",").tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a'], ['z'], nan]
```